# link firstpage and lastpage on will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Is there any link to show up firstpage and lastpage on will_paginate in rails ?

Comment: if you do `<%= will_paginate @objects %>` in your view, all the links will come if you have more than 1 page.

Comment: yes like that but only show previous page, next page and the link number. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try these links

http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/building-custom-pagination-links-with-will_paginate

http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate